# Highcharts showing image in tooltip and get column index

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts javascript library with the column chart. What I am trying to do is show an image in a tooltip when the user rolls over the column. I am able to show images, but not the one I want.

I have an array of image links

```
var imagesLinks = ["img1","img2","img3","imgN"];
```

What I am trying to do is show the image based upon which column they are on so if they on the first column it would show imagesLinks[0], third column would show imageLinks[img3] etc.

Basically I need to know how to get the column index. I found this code below that helps me get the images on click, but it does not really help with the tooltip.

```
plotOptions: {
     column :{
        point:{
           events:{
                click:function(){
                    console.log(this.x);
                  }
               }
          }
     }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Inside the formatter function you use `this.point.x`